# line spacing NSTextView

Tags: cocoa

If you install Microsoft word on Mac and open a document, you can increase line spacing to 2 by hitting Command + 2. Now my cocoa app uses NSTextView. And my users want a similar functionality in the app. I looked at the NSTextView apis and could not find any which will help me here. Is this something that can be accomplished using the defaults write command may be ?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Text Views are views to display their model, `NSTextStorage`. `NSTextStorage` is a subclass of `NSAttributedString`. You need to modify the attributes of the text for custom line spacing.