# Setting the Line Height/ Line Spacing in an NSTextView of Xamarin.mac

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.mac

How would I set the Line Height or Line Spacing in an NSTextView (i.e. how tall each line is, or how much space is between each line)in xamarin.mac ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [line spacing NSTextView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618815/line-spacing-nstextview)